# Need test class help

Tags: apex, unit-test, before-trigger

I want to increase my test class code coverage.as of now my code coverage is 68%. Please help me to get 100% code coverage. Below is my Test class and Trigger
Trigger:

```
trigger BIGDEAL on Opportunity (Before update)
{
    set<Id> oppIds = new set<Id>();
    set<id> uids = new set<id>();
    List<Opportunity> OppList = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id,List<Opportunitysplit>> oppMap = new Map<Id,List<Opportunitysplit>>();
    //OPTY TEAM Start
    Map<Id,List<OpportunityTeamMember>> oppTeam = new Map<Id,List<OpportunityTeamMember>>();
    //OPTY TEAM END
    Map<Id,List<partner>> opppartMap = new Map<Id,List<partner>>();
    Map<Id,Sales_Scorecard__c> sscMap = new Map<Id,Sales_Scorecard__c>();
    List<Sales_Scorecard__c> ssList = new List<Sales_Scorecard__c>();

    for(Opportunitysplit ops :[Select id,SplitAmount,SplitPercentage,Role_Name__c,Opportunityid,SplitOwnerid from Opportunitysplit Where Opportunityid IN: trigger.newmap.keyset()])
    {
        uids.add(ops.SplitOwnerid);
        if(oppMap.containskey(ops.Opportunityid))
        oppmap.get(ops.Opportunityid).add(ops);
        else{
            List<Opportunitysplit> opslist = new List<Opportunitysplit>();
            opslist.add(ops);
            oppmap.put(ops.Opportunityid,opslist);
        }
    }
    
    List<Sales_Scorecard__c> ssclist =[select id, name,User_Name__c,Manager__c,Quota__c,Manager_Quota__c,User_Role__c from Sales_Scorecard__c where User_Name__c IN :uids];
    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('GEIP-Renewal').getRecordTypeId();
    for(Sales_Scorecard__c ssc : ssclist){
        sscMap.put(ssc.User_Name__c,ssc);
    }
    List<partner> partnrs = [select OpportunityId,Role,AccountToId,AccountTo.name  from partner where OpportunityId IN:trigger.newmap.keyset()];
    for(partner pt: partnrs ){
        if(opppartMap.containskey(pt.OpportunityId))
        opppartMap.get(pt.OpportunityId).add(pt);
        else{
            List<partner> partnrlist = new List<partner>();
            partnrlist .add(pt);
            opppartMap.put(pt.Opportunityid,partnrlist);
        }
    }
    /*OPTY TEAM START
    List<OpportunityTeamMember> oppsTeam = [SELECT Id,Name,OpportunityId,TeamMemberRole,UserId FROM OpportunityTeamMember Where Opportunityid IN: trigger.newmap.keyset()];
    for(OpportunityTeamMember OPT: oppsTeam ){
        if(oppTeam.containskey(OPT.OpportunityId))
        oppTeam.get(OPT.OpportunityId).add(OPT);
        else{
            List<OpportunityTeamMember> opTeamList = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>();
            opTeamList.add(OPT);
            oppTeam.put(OPT.Opportunityid,opTeamList);
        }   
    }
    /OPTY TEAM END*/
    
   /* Map<Id,String> OppTeamMapRoles= New Map<id,String>();
    for(OpportunityTeamMember OPT: [SELECT Id,Name,OpportunityId,TeamMemberRole,UserId FROM OpportunityTeamMember Where Opportunityid IN: oppMap.keyset() and (TeamMemberRole IN ('SW Channel Manager','SW Account Manager'))]){
          
           OppTeamMapRoles.put(OPT.OpportunityId,OPT.TeamMemberRole);
          
    } */
    

    Map<Id,integer> OppTeamMapChannelRoles= New Map<id,integer>();
    
    Map<Id,integer> OppTeamMapAccountRoles= New Map<id,integer>();
    
    AggregateResult[] teamOppChannelCount =[SELECT OpportunityId,Count(id)FROM OpportunityTeamMember Where 
    Opportunityid IN: oppMap.keyset() and TeamMemberRole ='SW Channel Manager' GROUP BY OpportunityId];
    
    AggregateResult[] teamOppAccountCount =[SELECT OpportunityId,Count(id)FROM OpportunityTeamMember Where 
    Opportunityid IN: oppMap.keyset() and TeamMemberRole ='SW Account Manager' GROUP BY OpportunityId];
 

    for(AggregateResult ar : teamOppChannelCount){
        OppTeamMapChannelRoles.put((id)ar.get('OpportunityId'),(Integer)ar.get('expr0'));
    }
    
    for(AggregateResult ar : teamOppAccountCount){
        OppTeamMapAccountRoles.put((id)ar.get('OpportunityId'),(Integer)ar.get('expr0'));
    }
    

    for(opportunity opp : trigger.new)
    {
        system.debug('testing opp'+opp);
        if(oppMap.get(opp.id)!=null)
        {
            System.debug('*******--***'+opp);
            for(Opportunitysplit opss : oppMap.get(opp.id))
            {
                //      
               /* for(OpportunityTeamMember OPT : oppTeam.get(opp.id))
                {*/  
                    if((opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Best Case' || opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Commit') 
                    && opp.RecordTypeId== devRecordTypeId 
                    && sscmap!=null 
                    && sscmap.get(opss.SplitOwnerid)!=null 
                    //  && (opss.Role_Name__c =='SW Channel Manager'||opss.Role_Name__c =='SW Account Manager')
                    //&& (OPT.TeamMemberRole =='SW Channel Manager' || OPT.TeamMemberRole =='SW Account Manager')
                    && ((sscMap.get(opss.SplitOwnerid).Quota__c!=null
                    && (sscMap.get(opss.SplitOwnerid).Quota__c/2 <= opss.SplitAmount))
                    || (sscMap.get(opss.SplitOwnerid).Manager_Quota__c!=null 
                    &&  opss.SplitAmount >=sscMap.get(opss.SplitOwnerid).Manager_Quota__c*25/100)))
                    {   system.debug('testing opp'+opss );
                        opp.Big_Deal__c=true;
                        break;
                    }
                    
                     else if((opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Best Case' || opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Commit') && 
                                   // (OppTeamMapRoles.get(opp.id) =='SW Channel Manager'|| OppTeamMapRoles.get(opp.id)=='SW Account Manager')
                                   ( OppTeamMapChannelRoles.get(opp.id) > 1 || OppTeamMapAccountRoles.get(opp.id) > 1 )){
                          opp.Big_Deal__c=true;
                     }
                    
                    else if((opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Best Case' || opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Commit')
                    && !opp.Owner_Role__c.contains('Partner User')&&date.valueOf(opp.createdDate).daysBetween(date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate))<=30
                    ){
                        system.debug('testing opp'+opp.Owner_Role__c);
                        system.debug('testing opp'+date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate).daysBetween(date.valueOf(opp.createdDate)));
                        opp.Big_Deal__c=true;
                    }
                    else if((opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Best Case' || opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Commit')&&opp.Owner_Role__c.contains('Partner User')&&(date.valueOf(opp.createdDate).daysBetween(date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate))<=45))
                    {  
                        system.debug('testing opp'+date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate).daysBetween(date.valueOf(opp.createdDate))); 
                        opp.Big_Deal__c=true;
                    }
                    //else if(opppartMap!=null && opppartMap.get(opp.id)!=null)
                    else if((opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Best Case' || opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Commit') && opppartMap!=null && opppartMap.get(opp.id)!=null)
                    { for(partner pt : opppartMap.get(opp.id)) 
                        if(pt.AccountTo.name.contains('GE Intelligent platforms')&&(date.valueOf(opp.createdDate).daysBetween(date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate))<=30))
                        {opp.Big_Deal__c=true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(!pt.AccountTo.name.contains('GE Intelligent platforms')&&(date.valueOf(opp.createdDate).daysBetween(date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate))<=45))
                        opp.Big_Deal__c=true;
                        else{
                            system.debug('testing opp');
                            opp.Big_Deal__c=false;
                        }
                    }
                    //
                    /*else if(opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Best Case' || opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Commit')
                        { 
                        for(OpportunityTeamMember OPT: oppTeam.get(opp.id))
                            if(OPT.TeamMemberRole == 'SW Channel Manager' || OPT.TeamMemberRole =='SW Account Manager')
                            {opp.Big_Deal__c=true;
                            }
                        }*/
                        /*else if((opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Best Case' || opp.ForecastCategoryName=='Commit')&& OPT.TeamMemberRole == 'SW Channel Manager' || OPT.TeamMemberRole =='SW Account Manager'){
                            opp.Big_Deal__c=true;
                        }*/
                        
                    else{
                        system.debug('testing opp');
                        opp.Big_Deal__c=false;
                    }
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@istest(Seealldata=true)
private class BIGDEALTest{    
    static testMethod void BIGDEAL(){
        
      Id profileId = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'Standard User'].Id;
       
          User u =[select id,UserRole.name from user where id !=: userinfo.getUserid() limit 1];
          User u1 =[select id from user where id !=: userinfo.getUserid() AND id !=: u.id  limit 1];
           Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('GEIP-Renewal').getRecordTypeId();
           
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name='TestAcc';
        acc.salesAreaList__c = '';
        acc.BillingCountry = 'SLOVAKIA';
        acc.BillingCity = 'test city';
        acc.BillingStreet = 'test street';
        acc.ShippingCountry = 'SLOVAKIA';
        acc.SAP_Customer_Number__c = '123';
        acc.CSN__c='CSN1234';
        insert acc;
        
        Account accNew = new Account();
        accNew.Name='TestAcc2';
        accNew.salesAreaList__c = '';
        accNew.BillingCountry = 'SLOVAKIA';
        accNew.BillingCity = 'test city';
        accNew.BillingStreet = 'test street';
        accNew.ShippingCountry = 'SLOVAKIA';
        accNew.SAP_Customer_Number__c = '123';
        accNew.CSN__c='CSN1234';
        insert accNew;
        
        Opportunity Opp = TestFactory.getOpportunity();           
        Opp.Name = 'Opportunity record';       
        Opp.CloseDate = system.today()-3;
        Opp.Amount = 100;
        Opp.accountid = acc.id;
        //Opp.StageName =  'S8- Closed Won';
        //Opp.Owner_Role__c = u.id;
        Opp.StageName = 'S3- Discovery';
        Opp.Government_Funded_Opportunity__c = 'No' ;
        Opp.won_Loss_Reason__c = 'Test';  
        Opp.Big_Deal__c = False;
        Opp.ForecastCategoryName = 'Best Case';
         //test.starttest();
        insert Opp;
       /* Opp.Big_Deal__c =True;
        Opp.ForecastCategoryName = 'Commit';
        update Opp;*/
       // test.stoptest();
         list<OpportunitySplit> lstToInsert = new list<OpportunitySplit>();  
        OpportunitySplit oppSplit = new OpportunitySplit();
        oppSplit.OpportunityId = opp.id;
        oppSplit.SplitNote = 'test';
        oppSplit.SplitPercentage= 100;
      //  oppSplit.SplitAmount = 2000;
        oppSplit.SplitOwnerid= u.id;
        oppSplit.Role_Name__c = 'SW Channel Manager';
        lstToInsert.add(oppSplit);
        
          OpportunitySplit oppSplit1 = new OpportunitySplit();
          oppSplit1.OpportunityId = opp.id;
          oppSplit1.SplitNote = 'test';
          oppSplit1.SplitPercentage= 100;
       //  oppSplit1.SplitAmount = 2000;
          oppSplit1.SplitOwnerid= u.id;
          oppSplit1.Role_Name__c = 'SW Account Manager';
    
                  
        OpportunityTeamMember oppTeam = new OpportunityTeamMember();
        oppTeam.Userid = u.Id;
        oppTeam.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
        oppTeam.TeamMemberRole = 'SW Account Manager';
        oppTeam.TeamMemberRole = 'SW Channel Manager';
        insert oppTeam;
        
        
        Sales_Scorecard__c SalesScore = new Sales_Scorecard__c();
        SalesScore.Name = 'Test';
        SalesScore.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        SalesScore.Quota__c = 1000;
        SalesScore.Manager_Quota__c = 2000;
        Insert SalesScore;
        Opp.Big_Deal__c =True;
        Opp.ForecastCategoryName = 'Commit';
        update Opp;
        
        Partner thisPartner = new Partner();
        thisPartner.Role = 'Test Role';
        thisPartner.IsPrimary = true;
        thisPartner.OpportunityId = opp.id;
        thisPartner.AccountToId = accNew.id;
        insert thisPartner;
        
        
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you famililar with the developer console? If you open your trigger with it, you'll be able to see wich parts of the code aren't covered.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement wich is not reached contains many conditions. If you want to reach this statement you have to add this in your test class:

```
Opp.RecordTypeId = devRecordTypeId;
SalesScore.User_Name__c = u.Id;
oppSplit.SplitAmount = 500;
```

Comment: ,When am trying to add " oppSplit.SplitAmount = 500;" getting error like  Field is not writeable: OpportunitySplit.SplitAmount.   Can you please tell me how to avoid this one